# What should my life/damage be at the end of each difficulty?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

When I got to the end of act 3 in nightmare, I had ~7500 life and ~1100 damage.  At this point I started dying constantly, I mean like every yellow or blue monster pull meant at least 5 consecutive deaths.  I was wearing the best gear I had found, so I decided to check the auction house for the first time to spend some of this cash I had saved up.

About 35K later I was at ~10,000 life and ~2700 damage.  Things got much easier.  Now I'm back in the same boat with dying all the time and I was wondering what the par is for each act and difficulty.

I am a 54 monk and I run around with lightning fists as a spirit generator (extra spirit on crit) and tail kick (stun) as the spender.  I use the heal spell (extra healing), dodge mantra, auqa companion and aoe aura (extended range).  I have 2 one handers and stack only dex and a little vitality in gear so far.

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your question, like what class you're playing, what level you are, what kind of build you're running, etc.? You're more likely to get an answer that is helpful to you that way. As it is, not knowing your class or level, it's very hard to judge your effectiveness.

Comment: Personally, I find that I have less and less of a life the more I play.

Comment: I'm in inferno mode with 32k life and dealing 13k damage....if that helps

Answer (score 1):

There are no exact answer to how muck dmg or hp you should have at different levels. This varies very depending on your build, class and so on. The important part is to try and build your character optimal by concentrating on getting a few set of attributes. One way of knowing how your gear is doing is to see what required levels they have. It is not exact science but if you have an item that has a level requirement of more than twenty levels below your current level you can be pretty sure that you need to upgrade that item.

Answer (score 1):

Stack vitality and dex, use seize the initiative as a passive to get armor up, resolve to get enemy damage reduced by 25% and transcendence to heal you based on how much spirit you use.

You should farm act 3 for money and buy new gear, you don't really need resistance at that point but you'll need increased attack speed, search for weapons with dex, vit and attack speed. Get rings with vit and attack speed too, the faster you attack the more damage you deal and the more spirit you generate.

I'm level 55 right now on act 1 hell and it's pretty ridiculous. At 5k DPS and 22k HP I'm still having trouble with certain mobs but it's not back to back deaths

Answer (score 0):

Why would there be an exact build on how much HP you would have and how much damage you would need on every Act/Difficulty?

1. If you're struggling to keep up with the monsters, you probably need to upgrade your items.
2. If you're killing the monsters very easily you could probably be cleared to move on to the next Act/Difficulty.
3. The sky's the limit for your HP and DMG (well, not really) but in D3, ITS ALL ABOUT THE LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOT